# Opencv is working for my project on my laptop but stop working on raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, gstreamer, openvino

Good morning all! I despair (This is my first post).
I am trying to set up a human detection system using the openvino toolkit. I am using an example project provided by openvino at the following [openvino multi target tracking](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/tree/master/demos/python_demos/multi_camera_multi_target_tracking). I first tested them on my computer (ubuntu) and it worked. I have now tried to run the project on raspberry pi but it gets stuck at opencv level. I followed the following tutorial [Install openvino on rasbian](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.2/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_raspbian.html) for setting up openvino.
While debugging, I realized that the problem was with cv2.videocapure (link). Apparently there is a problem with the backend ffmepg but also GStreamer.

I run the following command

```
python3 multi_camera_multi_target_tracking.py     -i http://192.168.137.160:4747/video    --m_detector model/intel/person-detection-retail-0013/FP32/person-detection-retail-0013.xml     --m_reid model/intel/person-reidentification-retail-0031/FP32/person-reidentification-retail-0031.xml     --config config.py -l /opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/intel64/libcpu_extension_avx2.so
```

And i have the following results

```
INFO: 2021-03-07 21:07:34: Opening file http://192.168.137.160:4747/video
[DEBUG:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/videoio_registry.cpp (171) VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Builtin backends(8): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); MSMF(970); V4L2(960); CV_IMAGES(950); CV_MJPEG(940); UEYE(930)

[DEBUG:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/videoio_registry.cpp (195) VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Available backends(8): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); MSMF(970); V4L2(960); CV_IMAGES(950); CV_MJPEG(940); UEYE(930)

[ INFO:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/videoio_registry.cpp (197) VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Enabled backends(8, sorted by priority): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); MSMF(970); V4L2(960); CV_IMAGES(950); CV_MJPEG(940); UEYE(930)

[ WARN:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (108) open VIDEOIO(FFMPEG): trying capture filename='http://192.168.137.160:4747/video' ...

[ INFO:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (359) getPluginCandidates VideoIO pluigin (FFMPEG): glob is 'libopencv_videoio_ffmpeg*.so', 1 location(s)

[ INFO:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (366) getPluginCandidates     - /opt/intel/openvino/opencv/lib: 1

[ INFO:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (370) getPluginCandidates Found 1 plugin(s) for FFMPEG

[ INFO:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (175) libraryLoad load /opt/intel/openvino/opencv/lib/libopencv_videoio_ffmpeg.so => FAILED

[ WARN:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (170) open VIDEOIO(FFMPEG): backend is not available (plugin is missing, or can't be loaded due dependencies or it is not compatible)

[ WARN:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (108) open VIDEOIO(GSTREAMER): trying capture filename='http://192.168.137.160:4747/video' ...

[ INFO:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (359) getPluginCandidates VideoIO pluigin (GSTREAMER): glob is 'libopencv_videoio_gstreamer*.so', 1 location(s)

[ INFO:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (366) getPluginCandidates     - /opt/intel/openvino/opencv/lib: 1

[ INFO:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (370) getPluginCandidates Found 1 plugin(s) for GSTREAMER

[ INFO:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (175) libraryLoad load /opt/intel/openvino/opencv/lib/libopencv_videoio_gstreamer.so => OK

[ INFO:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/backend_plugin.cpp (236) PluginBackend Video I/O: loaded plugin 'GStreamer OpenCV Video I/O plugin'

[ INFO:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (711) open OpenCV | GStreamer: http://192.168.137.160:4747/video

[ INFO:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (744) open OpenCV | GStreamer: mode - URI
```

The program seems to be stuck there. No exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be because there is no FFmpeg installed or your FFmpeg version is not compatible with the OpenCV. Here is the guide to [install FFmpeg on Raspberry Pi](https://gist.github.com/dudewheresmycode/154df74824aadef2b8c1b8a6bccb66c7).

GStreamer is a complex framework with dozens of plugins that are used to build complex video processing pipelines. Looks like in your case something is wrong with MJPEG decoding performed via V4L2 interface, it can be caused by missing drivers or packages, or configuration issues. Take a look at this similar problem: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=249377.